# How to add vertical interactive guide line to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to build a fairly simple line chart with Chart.js but I need it to have a vertical guide line that shows up along with the tooltop when you hover over a point. I want something very similar to http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html but using Chart.js.

Here is an example of what I want that I cobbled together from various examples. Notice that the line disappears when you hover over a point.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [{
      fill: true,
      label: 'You',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,170,238, 0.5)',
      data: [8, 16, 30, 15, 12, 4]
    }, {
      fill: true,
      label: 'Others',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(153,170,238, 0.5)',
      data: [5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x-axis',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffe0',
      bodyFontColor: '#000',
      bodySpacing: 7,
      multiKeyBackground: '#ffffe0',
      titleFontColor: '#000',
      titleMarginBottom: 5,
      xPadding: 10,
      yPadding: 10
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }]
    }
  }
});

// Hook into main event handler
var parentEventHandler = Chart.Controller.prototype.eventHandler;
Chart.Controller.prototype.eventHandler = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var ret = parentEventHandler.apply(this, arguments);
  this.clear();
  this.draw();
  // Draw the vertical line here
  var eventPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(arguments[0], this.chart);
  this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
  this.chart.ctx.moveTo(eventPosition.x, 0);
  this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
  this.chart.ctx.lineTo(eventPosition.x, this.chart.height);
  this.chart.ctx.stroke();

  return ret;
};

<canvas id="myChart" height=200/>
```